# KDE5 keybind terminal applications

Tags: terminal, plasma, kde5

After over one hour trying to figure and set it out, I still can't get a simple keybind to launch a terminal application other than the terminal itself with KDE Plasma 5.

I have the terminal bound to `Meta+return` which works fine.
But any terminal application like *htop*, *pulsemixer* or any other won't launch after defining the binding with the kde shortcuts menu `(system settings > shortcuts > add application..)` which was exactly what I did for the terminal keybind.

All terminal apps run ok if called with krunner or the applications menu, but none seems to respond with an actual keybind. How to solve this?

Comment: By "terminal application", I assume you mean "An application designed to run in a text based terminal sessions (aka, a TUI, rather than a GUI)", and not "Run the application called 'Terminal'". Generally, you need to start a terminal session, and direct it to start the desired TUI application. Research that a bit, and come back here if you have a specific problem or still have trouble.

Comment: Exactly, I have expressed it wrong but you got it! Guess the question would be how to assign a keybind to open a terminal and run the application X.

Comment: Here's a hint, open a terminal window and try `man konsole`, `man gnome-terminal`, or whichever is your default/preferred terminal/console session application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out messing around with the `Custom shortcuts` there's some examples which I overlooked, so for future:

`Custom Shortcuts > Edit > New > Global Shortcuts > Command/URL`

1. Type in a description in the `Comments` tab (if needed)
2. Set the keybind in the `Trigger` tab
3. Invoke the terminal followed by the application name at `Action` tab (e.g. `konsole htop`)